# Make sssd respect Acctive Directory nested groups

Tags: active-directory, debian-wheezy, sssd

I have managed to get sssd working and `getent passwd *username*` as well as `getent group` returns AD data.
I am now facing a problem with nested groups in Active Directory.

In the AD i have supergroup for the entire department. This group has the users as members.

```
Department group: CN=123 - DepartmentName,OU=departments,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=company,DC=country
member CN=Benny Bob,OU=123 - DepartmentName,OU=other,OU=info,DC=company,DC=country
member CN=Billy Bob,OU=123 - DepartmentName,OU=other,OU=info,DC=company,DC=country
memberOf CN=RepositoryAuthorization,OU=Roles,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=company,DC=country
```

I also have a number of users, for example:

```
User : CN=Benny Bob,OU=xxx - DepartmentName,OU=other,OU=info,DC=company,DC=country
memberOf CN=xxx - DepartmentName,OU=departments,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=company,DC=country (The department group)
memberOf CN=ServerAuthorization,OU=Roles,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=company,DC=country
```

When i call `getent group | grep ServerAuthorization`the users (which are directly linked to the group) show up fine.
However, when i call `getent group | grep RepositoryAuthorization` they are shown as having no members. RepositoryAuthorization is a member of the department group, that the users are members of. So its a nested group.

I assume its a problem with my sssd setup.
EDIT:
This does not seem  to be a problem of nesting directions.
It seems that certain groups are simply not retrieved by SSSD.

All groups in `OU=Roles,OU=Security Groups....` are returned by `getent group`. However, groups in `OU=Departments,OU=Security Groups....` are not.

Settings are `ldap_group_search_base = OU=Security Groups...` and 'ldap_group_nesting_level = 100'

This is the log for the `getent group` call (Loglevel 7) I am especially curious about this:

```
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0080): ldap_search_ext failed: Bad search filter
    (Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_done] (0x0100): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed [1432158235]: Malformed search filter
    (Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,1432158235,Init group lookup failed
```

Full log:

```
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:15 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0100): Got request for [4098][1][*]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:15 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_req_set_domain] (0x0400): Changing request domain from [Company.dk] to [Company.dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:15 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_handle_acct_req_send] (0x1000): Skipping group enumeration on demand
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:15 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 0,0,Success
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0100): Got request for [4099][1][name=localUser]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_req_set_domain] (0x0400): Changing request domain from [Company.dk] to [Company.dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_initgr_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=localUser)(objectclass=user)((null)=*))][ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk].
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [sAMAccountName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gecos]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [unixHomeDirectory]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginShell]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPrincipalName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [displayName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [memberOf]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [modifyTimestamp]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uSNChanged]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowLastChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMin]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMax]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowWarning]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowInactive]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowExpire]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowFlag]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbLastPwdChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbPasswordExpiration]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [pwdAttribute]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [authorizedService]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [accountExpires]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userAccountControl]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [nsAccountLock]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [host]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginDisabled]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginExpirationTime]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginAllowedTimeMap]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0080): ldap_search_ext failed: Bad search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_done] (0x0100): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed [1432158235]: Malformed search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,1432158235,Init group lookup failed
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0100): Got request for [4099][1][name=localUser]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_req_set_domain] (0x0400): Changing request domain from [Company.dk] to [Company.dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_initgr_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=localUser)(objectclass=user)((null)=*))][ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk].
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [sAMAccountName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gecos]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [unixHomeDirectory]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginShell]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPrincipalName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [displayName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [memberOf]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [modifyTimestamp]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uSNChanged]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowLastChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMin]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMax]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowWarning]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowInactive]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowExpire]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowFlag]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbLastPwdChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbPasswordExpiration]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [pwdAttribute]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [authorizedService]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [accountExpires]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userAccountControl]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [nsAccountLock]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [host]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginDisabled]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginExpirationTime]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginAllowedTimeMap]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0080): ldap_search_ext failed: Bad search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_done] (0x0100): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed [1432158235]: Malformed search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,1432158235,Init group lookup failed
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0100): Got request for [4099][1][name=localUser]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_req_set_domain] (0x0400): Changing request domain from [Company.dk] to [Company.dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_initgr_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=localUser)(objectclass=user)((null)=*))][ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk].
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [sAMAccountName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gecos]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [unixHomeDirectory]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginShell]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPrincipalName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [displayName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [memberOf]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [modifyTimestamp]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uSNChanged]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowLastChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMin]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMax]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowWarning]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowInactive]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowExpire]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowFlag]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbLastPwdChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbPasswordExpiration]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [pwdAttribute]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [authorizedService]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [accountExpires]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userAccountControl]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [nsAccountLock]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [host]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginDisabled]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginExpirationTime]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginAllowedTimeMap]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0080): ldap_search_ext failed: Bad search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_done] (0x0100): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed [1432158235]: Malformed search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,1432158235,Init group lookup failed
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_get_account_info] (0x0100): Got request for [4099][1][name=localUser]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [be_req_set_domain] (0x0400): Changing request domain from [Company.dk] to [Company.dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_initgr_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=localUser)(objectclass=user)((null)=*))][ou=Users,ou=Company,dc=Company,dc=dk].
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [sAMAccountName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gecos]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [unixHomeDirectory]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginShell]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPrincipalName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [displayName]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [memberOf]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [modifyTimestamp]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uSNChanged]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowLastChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMin]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowMax]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowWarning]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowInactive]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowExpire]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [shadowFlag]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbLastPwdChange]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [krbPasswordExpiration]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [pwdAttribute]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [authorizedService]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [accountExpires]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userAccountControl]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [nsAccountLock]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [host]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginDisabled]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginExpirationTime]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [loginAllowedTimeMap]
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0080): ldap_search_ext failed: Bad search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [sdap_get_generic_done] (0x0100): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed [1432158235]: Malformed search filter
(Tue Jan 27 15:58:25 2015) [sssd[be[Company.dk]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,1432158235,Init group lookup failed
```

Comment: That's not how nested groups work... Just because user 1 is a member of group A and group B is a member of group A doesn't mean user 1 is also a member of group B. Nesting means user 1 is in group A, group A is in group B, therefore user 1 is in group B.

Comment: Isn't that what i have? User 1 (Benny) is in Department(Group A) Repo(Group B) is in Department(GroupA).

I might be getting confused by member and memberOf, but in my case, GroupA(Dept) has 'member' on User1(Benny) and GroupB(Repo) has 'member" on GroupA(Dept).
Shouldn't this work?

Comment: You have:  1->A + B->A.  You need:  1->A + A->B.

Comment: I am very sorry for being confused, but it seems to be that's what i have. I have: u1 'memberof' gA   |   gA 'member' u1     gA 'memberOf' gB  |  gB 'member' gA...    So 1 memberOf A + A memberOf B

Comment: Your initial description indicated case 1. If you do indeed have case 2, then you should be okay, and there is a problem with sssd somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just realized that when i do a getent group | grep "theDepartmentName" it isn't returned. It seems that sssd does not retrieve the department group. All groups have the same object class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the sssd.conf I gave you on your [Wheezy SSSD-AD question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181309/100397) over on StackExchange. You need the `ldap_group_nesting_level = 5` entry to enable nested groups.

Comment: I did see it. I've tried 2, 10, 100 and now 5 :)

What is odd, as i write in the question, is that the "department" groups are not even returned by getent, even though they have members in them directly.

Comment: OK. We will get there, I'm sure. 1. Are you using "sss" in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? You need it on the end of the lines for passwd, group, netgroup, and possibly sudoers. 2. `getent group` will not enumerate all your AD groups so you can't `grep`. But you can do `getent group _groupname_` and it will perform a lookup on the named _groupname_. I've also confirmed that my `getent group _groupname_` really does unroll nested group memberships.

Comment: Damnit, i figured it out. The group search based missed a critical aggregation group that was between the users and the permission groups. Its working splendidly. Except for one group that is a member of domain users in OU=users,DC=cmp,DC=dk. This should add the group to all users, but it does not. But that is a minor annoyance i can work around:)

Answer (score 2):

According to the logs SSSD was also complaining about a malformed filter:
`(&(sAMAccountName=localUser)(objectclass=user)((null)=*))`

Looks like you're using ID mapping along with the LDAP (not AD) provider in which case you need to configure the ldap_user_objectsid value:

`ldap_user_objectsid = objectSid`